# Changing boolean value within a DataFrame iterrows does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The general idea is:

1. Read a DataFrame from Excel
2. Add a new column where I can identify valid and invalid rows (in this example, values are initialized at `None`, but I've also tried initializing at `False` and `0`)
3. Iterate through DataFrame and assign values to the new column depending on a series of tests. (unfortunately, the tests are too complex to use `applymap` or similar)

The expected result is to print the DataFrame and see the values of the new column properly assigned.

The experienced result is the values have not changed at all. They all remain in their initial value.

Here's a highly simplified code sample, where the behavior is present.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./some_file.csv', sep='\t')

print(df)   # View outputs below

df['Valid'] = [None for _ in range(len(df))]    # New column

for n in df.iterrows():
    if pd.notnull(n[1].Name):    # Example test
        n[1].Valid = False
    else:    # else clause should ensure all values change
        n[1].Valid = True

print(df)    # Shows all df.Valid values are still None
```

Output 1 after `read_csv()`

```
    Name  Age
0   John   20
1  Mandy   25
2   Mike   30
3    NaN   40
4   Alex   35
```

Output 2 at the end of the code:

```
    Name  Age Valid
0   John   20  None
1  Mandy   25  None
2   Mike   30  None
3    NaN   40  None
4   Alex   35  None
```

In the example above, when printing `df`, all values are still `None`, even though the debugger shows the process stepping into the assignment statements.

Is there some sort of scope, reference, or mutability issue that I'm not seeing? Can anybody explain this behavior?

Running python 3.6.0

For a sample data set, I manually built a `some_file.csv` file separated by tabs with (4th row has an empty string for Name while age is 40, 5th row is skipped by `read_csv` for obvious reasons):

```
Name    Age
John    20
Mandy   25
Mike    30
    40

Alex    35
```

Comment: @StephenRauch I've edited the question to show sample outputs, and also changed the input file to a sample csv (contents detailed in the question also).

Comment: @StephenRauch Alright, I separated the code and the outputs for easy copy-paste. Don't know how to make the csv easier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Dataframe.iterrows()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) returns a Series which is a copy of the data.  It can not be used to update the underlying DataFrame.  Instead I suggest just building a list, and adding it to the Dataframe when done like:

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep='\t')

valid = []
for n in df.iterrows():
    if pd.notnull(n[1].Name):    # Example test
        valid.append(False)
    else:    # else clause should ensure all values change
        valid.append(True)
df['Valid'] = valid    # New column

print(df)    # Shows all df.Valid values are still None
```

#### Results:

```
    Name  Age  Valid
0   John   20  False
1  Mandy   25  False
2   Mike   30  False
3    NaN   40   True
4   Alex   35  False
```

Comment: This (looping) is definitely *not* how you should define a column. just do `df = df.assign(Valid=df['Name'].notnull())` (why null values would be "valid" I'll leave to the OP)

Comment: @PaulH, OP said this was a highly minimized example, and the work was extensive.

Comment: @PaulH Stephen is correct. The posted code is just simplified for clarity. In reality it's several tests performed, including cross-dependencies between series and multiple data frames. Using df.assign() or df.applymap() might be possible but also too hard to read for a one-time task with no performance requirements.

Comment: @JavoSN I promise you, it can be done without loops.