# I get an error when trying to compare dates in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, compare

I am trying to iterate through rows in a .csv file and perform some calculations if some conditions are met.

Here's my code sample:

I made sure to identify the date columns by using "parse_dates"

```
df = pd.read_csv('.csv file', parse_dates = ['Columns containing dates']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    Flag = (df['Date 1'] - df['Date 2']).dt.days
    while Flag > 0 and df['Balance'] > 0:
        do something
```

Removing the while loop, and printing Flag yields rows of numbers with a dtype of int64.

Adding the while loop, I get:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Which I am not understanding... Can someone point me the in the right direction? Also, I am not trying to modify the dataframe, but merely reading the .csv, extracting information from it to perform calculations, and output to a new file.

Comment: Both `Flag > 0` and `df['Balance'] > 0` evaluate to a Series, not to a number or a boolean. They cannot be combined with `and`. Your code is probably wrong in all other ways because you use a `for` loop but never refer to the loop variables. Without sample data and an explanation, you are unlikely to get any positive help.

Comment: "Both Flag > 0 and df['Balance'] > 0 evaluate to a Series, not to a number or a boolean. They cannot be combined with and. " Thanks, I did not know this about df, looks like I have some reading to do but at least I know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `Flag` in you code is a `pandas Series`. You cannot evaluate it with `Flag>0`.

The error shows you the permitted operations on pandas Series i.e., `.empty(), .bool(), etc.`.

When you print the value of `Flag` it prints the Series that it contains. You need to iterate over the elements in `Series` and then check for comparison as you want.

I am not sure you you want to compare here but below document might make it easy for you :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer and link. I did not know this about df so I will read up more on it. I also came across this other post that helped me and may help others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070320/changing-boolean-value-within-a-dataframe-iterrows-does-nothing

Comment: Great to hear that and good work sharing similar question. :)